# Map two identical models, nested with automapper

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, mapping, automapper, asp.net-core-3.0

I did some research but I couldn't find exactly what I wanted.

I have an endless menu. I have a MenuDTO and a MenuViewModel that I use for this menu. I had no problem matching between model and DTO, but am having trouble mapping DTO to ViewModel. Obviously I couldn't find the solution, can you help?

My MenuDTO Object

```
    public class MenuDto : BaseDto
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Icon { get; set; }
        public string Order { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public bool IsVisible { get; set; }
        public int ParentId { get; set; }
        public MenuDto ParentMenu { get; set; }
        public List<MenuDto> Menus { get; set; }
    }
```

And MenuViewModel

```
    public class MenuViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }        
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Icon { get; set; }
        public string Order { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public bool IsVisible { get; set; }
        public int ParentId { get; set; }
        public MenuViewModel ParentMenu { get; set; }
        public List<MenuViewModel> Menus { get; set; }
    }
```

This is how I mapped the MenuDTO and MenuViewModel objects.

```
    public class WebProfile : Profile
    {
        public WebProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<MenuDto, MenuViewModel>();
            CreateMap<MenuViewModel, MenuDto>();
        }
    }
```

I call this way in the controller

```
var navMenuItems = _mapper.Map<List<MenuViewModel>(_menuService.GetNavMenus());
```

Although all fields are mapped, I get an error on the Menus field.

The error message I get is;

```
AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
MenuDto -> MenuViewModel
BiPortal2020.Business.ServiceDTOs.Menu.MenuDto -> BiPortal2020.WebUI.Areas.Admin.Models.Menu.MenuViewModel
lambda_method(Closure , MenuDto , MenuViewModel , ResolutionContext )

AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
Object -> List`1
System.Object -> System.Collections.Generic.List`1
```

Comment: What's in `BaseDto`?

Comment: BaseDto has fields Id, DateCreated, DateModified, IsActive.

Comment: I don't see any problem with the mapping. Please fix the typo here - `_mapper.Map<List<MenuViewModel>(_menuService.GetNavMenus())` and let us know about the latest error message.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I keep getting the same error even though that line has -

`_mapper.Map<List<MenuViewModel>>(_menuService.GetNavMenus());`

Comment: Have you checked `_menuService.GetNavMenus()`? Is returning `List<MenuDto>`?

Comment: Yeap, Menu Service is return `List<MenuDto>`  - MenuService code `return _mapper.Map<List<MenuDto>>(navMenuItems);`

Comment: Have you added AutoMapper in the Startup.Configure() method? Are your mapping Profiles are in the same project as the Startup.cs, or in a separate project?

Comment: I have two profiles in the project. It is located in BusinessProfile -> Business layer, WebProfile-> UI layer. But it seems unreasonable to me that I have no problem mapping from Dto to Model and only for this field -  `public List<MenuViewModel> Menus { get; set; } `

Comment: Added an answer. Let us know if your issue still exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message implies - AutoMapper, either cannot map between `MenuDto` and `MenuViewModel`, or it cannot locate the defined mappings.

I've tested your mappings and they are totally fine. So, what possibility remains is AutoMapper cannot locate your mappings.

I'm Assuming the `Business Layer` and `UI Layer` you mentioned in the comment section are two separate projects. Since the `WebProfile` is defined in the `UI Layer`, you have to tell AutoMapper that it should search that assembly to find the mappings. Since your mappings between Models and DTOs are working, I can guess you've already done the same for `BusinessProfile` which is defined in the `Business Layer`.

I don't know about your existing code, but you could do something like this - in the `Startup.Configure` method add/modify the following line -

```cs
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(IDtoMapping), typeof(IViewModelMapping));
```

where `IDtoMapping` and `IViewModelMapping` are two marker interface (empty interface, used only to identify the assembly they are declared in) declared in the `Business Layer` and `UI Layer`, respectively.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I solved the problem in a similar way as you mentioned. Thank you for your support.